# Curl on an image returning text/html instead of image/jpeg

Tags: php, curl

I created a script to load an image from an URL using CURL. To test that the file is a JPG, I'm using ($info['content_type'] == 'image/jpeg').
It works on most of the urls, but some return a html type : e.g http://www.super-fond.fr/IMAGES_VOITURES/lexus/2005-Lexus-LF-A-Concept-R-1280x960.jpg
Could anyone tell me why this URL is html ?

Thanks

Comment: The only person who could tell you for sure is the owner of `super-fond.fr`, as this is a server configuration problem. I suspect Browsers looks at the extension as well to determine file type, which is why they can see it...

Comment: post the source code of your CURL steps

Comment: What is the content of the HTML?  It might just say that hot-linking is not allowed on the image.

Comment: I don't know why, but if you receive a text/html, you can use `imagecreatefromstring($string)` to check if it's an image.

Comment: Actually, looking at that specific image, it appears to be sending the proper content type, so I'm not sure...

Comment: $ch = curl_init($urlBase);
   $fp = fopen($name, 'wb');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
   if($info['content_type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
imagecreatefromstring is returning an error ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you not set a user-agent in request headers and this host rejects request with specific user-agent.

See `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` in [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) on how to set the user-agent:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla');
```

Comment: That should solve it. Checked with CURL on commandline, `-A Mozilla` serves a 200 OK instead of 403 Forbidden.